# concurrent connections in tornado

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, tornado

I have a server running on tornado. I have a page that opens a `websocket` to the same server. Now I have observed that opening multiple instances of this page makes all of them wait except one. Only after that one has finished its websocket, does another one start. Is this normal tornado behaviour of I'm doing something wrong?

Earlier my server was running with `django` but I migrated to `tornado` for the websocket support. For that I use fallback server as django.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Run this with
# PYTHONPATH=. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testsite.settings testsite/tornado_main.py
# Serves by default at
# http://localhost:8080/hello-tornado and
# http://localhost:8080/hello-django

from tornado.options import options, define, parse_command_line
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi

define('port', type=int, default=8000)

class HelloHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write('Hello from tornado')

def main():
  wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(
    django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
  tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
    [
      ('/hello-tornado', HelloHandler),
      ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
      ])
  server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
  server.listen(options.port)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Can I do something that can allow me to make multiple connections?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the Asych facilities in tornado to get this to work properly. Tornado in it's normal state is a single threaded stack and thus you can only handle one connection at a time.

You can use the normal @asynchronous decorator or use their gen library to allow your code to handle multiple connections.

Decorator: http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html#decorators

Gen: http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html

Read the documentation carefully if you choose to use the @asynchronous decorator as you need to close the connection when you are done with it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is normal Tornado behaviour in case when you trying run heavy blocking applications like Django in it.

You, definitely, should run django and tornado in separate OS processes. Especially if you use Django ORM.

Need I describe why?

Comment: Not why, but how?. If they run in different processes, how will they communicate?

Comment: @prongs: through some kind of RPC (JSON-RPC/raw HTTP or some kind of unix/tcp sockets). For example, you can add some internal RPC urls in tornado like `/send_realtime_message` and then call it from django like `urllib.request("http://tornado/send_realtime_message?user=user&messahe=Hello")`. But there is not a good idea to have many communications between Django app and Tornado server.

Comment: Python processes can also communicate by sharing data using Queues: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html